# How to get current location in react-router v2 outside of React component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Do I have to create my own service listening to history and keeping and updating its own location property?

I would expect something like this:

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

if (browserHistory.location.pathname.startsWith('/some/path')) {...}
```

It seems that location is directly available only in props in React components.

Comment: what are you trying to do? could you explain your use case?

Comment: Kind of a middleware or service which every http reponse goes through and provides a default handling for http errors, notably 401. I need to check if I'm already on /login and if not redirect to it. The check is needed because there might be multiple http request/responses running and I want to redirect only for the first one. It all happens outside of React components.

Comment: I have exactly the same use case as @petrn and came across this question while trying to figure out how to do it.